# Git: create a restorable snapshot of file without commit (spoiler: git stash don't work)

Tags: git

Sorry if this question has been asked (can't find it), but is it possible to create a "light" commit of a state, without creating a debug branch + commit + squash commits + reset master? I’m looking for a simple git equivalent of:

```
# save snapshot
$ cp myfile myfile-backup-before-big-tests
# restore snapshot
$ cp myfile-backup-before-big-tests myfile
```

Stash was quite close, but the issue is that:

1. `stash push` resets the current state of my files to their state at the previous commit. I don't want to change `myfile` at all.
2. `stash pop` would try to merge the content of the stash with HEAD. I want to completely restore the state.

**Motivations:** Sometimes, I have a state of my project that I like (e.g. it managed to pass the debug tests, but fail some other tests), and I’d like to create a snapshot of this state before diving into understanding why it fails to pass other tests. Most of the time, I will never revert back, but I’m afraid to break something while debugging so I want a restorable copy somewhere. One way to proceed could be to create a new debug branch, commit to that branch, do the debugging and somehow find a magic command to commit the final state to master (maybe a mix of squash and reset?)… but that's a quite complicated setting compared to the above procedure.

Comment: Make a new branch then commit to that branch. You don't need to push that branch

Comment: The problem with Git is that you have to explain how the model works in order to motivate why the straightforward answer to such a question makes sense.

Comment: @mousetail thanks, but I was hopping for a simpler strategy with less `git checkout` since I would need something like `git checkout -b dev; git commit; git checkout master; git merge --squash dev; git branch -d dev` even in a normal scenario where I don't need to revert the state (but the `git merge --squash` does simplify the final merging process), but if there is no other solution…

Comment: @tobiasBora a branch is extremely simple, I don't think a even simpler solution would even be possible

Comment: @mousetail sure, but I need to type like 5 commands (even if I don't need the backup) instead of 1 with cp… so in practice I’m often lazy and just go for cp when I have only one file to deal with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have 2 alias `git tempo` and `git undo`

```
undo=reset HEAD~1
tempo=commit -a --no-verify --no-gpg-sign -m tempo
```

This allow to create a tempo commit with `git tempo` to snapshot the state

then you can use `git reset --hard` to go back to this *saved* state

`git undo` remove the commit and keep the change to do a proper commit or delete changes

Comment: Oh, never realized that reset was leaving the changes, interesting. I guess this solution is not too bad, thanks.